# How to maintain state for each thread separately

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a field `int x` which is supposed to be accessed from many threads at the same time. I want `x` to have a separate copy per thread, each starting out at its original value. I tried to do this using the `volatile` keyword, but each new thread still modifies `x` for other threads.

Here is a code example:

```
public class StackOverflowThread0 {

    public StackOverflowThread0() {
        new A().start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StackOverflowThread0();
    }

    volatile int x = 0;//<--keep original for each thread?

    class A extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    getT().start();

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    Thread getT() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                x++;

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("x=" + x + " | thread id=" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "| 100*x+x=" + (100 * x + x));
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                interrupt();
            }
        };
        return t;
    }
}
```

the output is :

```
x=1 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=101
x=1 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=101
x=1 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=101
x=1 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=101
x=1 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=101
x=1 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=101
x=1 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=101
x=1 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=101
x=1 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=101
x=1 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=101 //thread 10 has x field value as 1
x=2 | thread id=11| 100*x+x=202 //thread 11 modifies x field to 2
x=2 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=202 //thread 10 lost x value as 1 :(

etc...
```

How do I keep a separate `x` value for each thread, or is there a more optimal way to solve the task?

Comment: Take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Comment: @TotZam yes, I tried atomic but seems it didn't work in the case I describe; Anyways I'll try again a bit later :)

Comment: @TotZam I think he was a separate value for each thread, not a common value for all threads.

Comment: @ReutSharabani I am not exactly sure how to combine the docs you gave me and the case I describe in my question; Please give more details

Comment: @TotZam Assuming this "x=2 | thread id=10| 100*x+x=202 //thread 10 lost x value as 1 :(" means he wants a unique value per thread. Note the sad face.

Comment: @user390525 volatile does not do what you want, in simple terms (without going into the complexities of volatile vs synchrnozed, etc) it does the opposite.

Comment: @ReutSharabani could you give an example of how to use ThreadLocal in my case?

Comment: Umm.. what is wrong with a 'normal' auto/stack 'X', or a data member of getT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) class can make this happen for you. It maintains a variable that is different for each thread that accesses it. In other words, each thread gets its own unique copy of the variable.

Check out the following changes to your code:

```
//Initialisation of the variable. Here an initial value of zero is assigned.
ThreadLocal<Integer> x = ThreadLocal.withInitial(()-> 0);

//Incrementing the value by one:
x.set(x.get() + 1);

//Outputting the result:
System.out.println("x=" + x.get() + " | thread id=" 
                            + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "| 100*x+x=" + (100 * x.get() + x.get()));
```

Edit: For those using 1.7, there is indeed a way to use ThreadLocal without the lambda expression. You'll have to override the initialValue() method, though.

```
ThreadLocal<Integer> x = new ThreadLocal<Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected Integer initialValue() {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same result avoiding lambda expressions? I am using 1.7 right now

Comment: Does ThreadLocal means thread 10 and thread 11 for example may have their own x value as 1; So x value may duplicate or not? Give more details

Comment: Each time a new thread tries to access the variable through threadLocal.get(), a new Integer instance is automatically created using the initialValue() method. That Integer instance belongs to one thread, and is invisible to all other threads. I hope this explains it.

Comment: @user390525 I'm not really sure what your question was, or what you mean by duplicate. But the value for thread 1 is completely seperate from the value for thread 2. They could be the same, but they don't have to be. If thread 1 sets the value, nothing happens to the value thread 2 is seeing.

Comment: By "duplicate" I mean each thread may have its own version of x; so x may have duplicate value; Anyways LocalThread is more close to correct way :)

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to Thread Local Storage, you can keep your **x** variable on your call stack.  Of course that depends on how you use **x**; you may actually need your variable on the heap.  And in that case you're better off with ThreadLocal.

Threads all share a heap, but [have their own stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30270646/is-there-a-stack-space-for-every-thread).

Which means any variables that are kept on the stack are immediately thread local.

Comment: Nice one, +1 for thinking outside the box.

Comment: I thought that way too but it is quite irrational :) As a temp solution I tried to integrate int mX=x in each overriden run() method; But, yes, ThreadLocal seems to be the standard way to solve the issue if "x is ok to be duplicated"